# Timing issue in Python codility challenge

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, time-complexity

I am trying to solve a Coding Challenge problem on Codility. The problem is as simple as follows: given the N x M grid The original code I obtained is [here](https://app.codility.com/cert/view/certK988NF-C57DZ6NRNARQZPED/details/)

Here is my improvement code, which changed the lines 35 and 43

```
cnt1 = 0;
cnt2 = 0;
# X = sorted(X);
# Y = sorted(Y);
if (M<1) | (N<1) | (N>100000) | (M>100000) | \
(len(X) % 2 != 0) | (max(X)>= N) | (max(Y) >= M) | (min(X)<0) | (min(Y) < 0) :
    return 0
elif (M==1) & (N==1):
    return 0
elif (M==1) & (N>=2):
    for i in range(N):
        y = [X[k] for k, x in enumerate(X) if x <= i]
        y2 = [X[k] for k, x in enumerate(X) if x>i]
        if(len(y) == len(y2)):  
            cnt1 = cnt1+1;
        else:  
            cnt1 = cnt1;
    return cnt1  
elif (N==1) & (M>=2):
    for i in range(M):
        y = [Y[k] for k, x in enumerate(Y) if x <= i]
        y2 =[Y[k] for k, x in enumerate(Y) if x >i]
        if(len(y) == len(y2)):
            cnt2 = cnt2+1;
        else: cnt2 = cnt2
    return cnt2
else: 
    for i in range(N):
        y = [X[k] for k, x in enumerate(X) if x <= i]
        y2 = [X[k] for k, x in enumerate(X) if x>i] #line 39
        if(len(y) == len(y2)):  
            cnt1 = cnt1+1;
        else:  
            cnt1 = cnt1;

    for i in range(M):
        y = [Y[k] for k, x in enumerate(Y) if x <= i]
        y2 = [Y[k] for k, x in enumerate(Y) if x>i] #line 45
        if(len(y) == len(y2)):
            cnt2 = cnt2+1;
        else: 
            cnt2 = cnt2
    return cnt1 + cnt2
```

I *improved* the time complexity to 33% with the above code, while correctness is 100% (see [here](https://app.codility.com/cert/view/cert274S8T-ES6KGBFRTJFXSFA9/details/)).

I then continued changing those two same lines (35, 43) as `y2 = set(X).difference(set(y))` and `y2 = set(Y).difference(set(y))`, but the time complexity was `0%` in this case. Correctness was also reduced to `87%`.

**Question:** Can somebody please help me improve the time complexity for the algorithm above? I am very curious to see how you can avoid using **nested for** loops in this particular problem (thus, obtaining `O(M+N+K)`)

Comment: Hi user177196, is it at all possible to put all the information required to answer the qusetion into the question (without having to follow links)? One reason is posterity; if the link goes down, we still want the question to be useful

Comment: @en_Knight: I am sorry, but in this case, the question is very long, so I thought the link is much more helpful? I don't want everyone to stay away from a long problem cause...you know, reading is sometimes...tough;p

Comment: that's fair, IMO people are less likely to follow a link and *then* read a long question than they are to read one that's inlined :)  As long as all of the information is "minimal and necessary" it's okay for it to be long. A cursory look at that link makes it clear that *not* everything is necessary. There's a fair amount of text about kings and their children, which is irrelevant to any programming problem. Maybe you don't need *any* of the text, and can put a reduced part of the code and then your attempt to optimize it, e.g., with the resultant problem in complexity

Comment: @en_Knight: Thank you for your sharing. I just realize that Codility prohibits "unauthorized copying" of their questions. I am editing my original answer to include my original code and my attempt to optimize it, together with the problem in complexity.

Comment: @en_Knight: I added my code as you requested. Please help me if you can, as I can only get 33% at best for the time complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when you need linear complexity, but can think of a quadratic solution, then think about precomputing things.

Code with improved complexity:

```
from itertools import accumulate
# use itertools accumulate to compute prefix sums, it not allowed, can simply write your own function
def solution(N, M, X, Y):
    # precompute the mines along rows and cols [O(k)]
    rows = [0 for i in range(N)]
    cols = [0 for j in range(M)]

    for k in range(len(X)):
        rows[X[k]]+=1
        cols[Y[k]]+=1

    # precompute the prefix sum and suffix sum( i.e the total mine grids from left/right upto, including this index ) [O(M+N)]
    r_left = list(accumulate(rows))
    r_right = list(reversed(list(accumulate(reversed(rows)))))

    c_left = list(accumulate(cols))
    c_right = list(reversed(list(accumulate(reversed(cols)))))

    # now horizontal splits possible at indices where the left and right accumulations are same [O(M+N)]
    pos_horizontal_spilts = sum([1 if r_left[i]==r_right[i]-rows[i] else 0 for i in range(N)])
    pos_vertical_spilts = sum([1 if c_left[j]==c_right[j]-cols[j] else 0 for j in range(M)])

    return pos_horizontal_spilts + pos_vertical_spilts
```

Example run:

```
solution(N = 5, M = 5, X = [0, 4, 2, 0], Y = [0, 0, 1, 4])
rows = [2, 0, 1, 0, 1]
cols = [2, 1, 0, 0, 1]
r_left, r_right = [2, 2, 3, 3, 4], [4, 2, 2, 1, 1]
c_left, c_right = [2, 3, 3, 3, 4], [4, 2, 1, 1, 1]
pos_horizontal_spilts = 2
pos_vertical_spilts = 1
```

P.S : I have not submitted it on codility, so some corner cases might be unhandled.

Comment: I tested your code, and it worked perfectly!! Thanks a ton for your help. However, by "precompute the mines along rows and cols", did you mean counting the number of x and y-coordinates (equivalent to number of given gold mines) from the given lists `X` and `Y`, and put it into a new list called `rows` and `cols` that have the size `N` and `M`, respectively?

Comment: Yes, imagine walking along the rows and counting the number of total mines in that row. Similarly for columns as well.